# How to make mysql slower on running query than hadoop?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, hadoop, time

I want to ask a little weird question. I have a hadoop project and I want to compare hadoop and mysql time performance. I already made hadoop application to count something. That application become COUNT query with join some table if translated into SQL.

First, I try with the small table with about 100.000 record on SQL, and it query about 0,3 or 0,4 seconds. So, I want to duplicate and enlarge the table with more records, to look the hadoop's feature than mysql. What with duplicate the data I can make hadoop greater than mysql? or what else I can do to prove tha hadoop time performance than mysql?

Comment: If you don't know how to go about achieving this end, then will you be able to understand and apply the information to be gained from the experiment?

Answer (score 1):

Inorder to get better performance than mysql, your data size should be very huge. For example, if your data is 1GB . you will be running 16 Mappers in parallel. if you data is less than 64 MB , you will be using a single Mapper and you wont see a performance hike in this case. So make sure your data is big enough to test the performance.

Comment: Thanks before....in your opinion is mysql time performance also depending on row number? I think with 100.000 record I get 0,3 second, when I multiply it, is it can make affect to slower query?

Thanks

Comment: yes. it has to scan all the rows to get you the result. Try to perform joins on huge dataset. instead of running a simple where clause. you can see more performance difference since join is a costly operation.

Comment: To be in a league with Hadoop, make sure the data set is larger than can be cached in RAM (for either Hadoop or MySQL).

Comment: so the table size is larger than RAM?